# Finding $\ T $ invariant subspaces of $\ V $

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to find any $\ T $ invariant subspace of $\ V$ where $\ T: V \rightarrow V  , V =\mathbb R^3$

$$\ T = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix} $$

So the a characteristic polynomial is $\ c_A(x) = (1-x)^2(2-x) $

$$\ E(1) = sp\{(1,0,0), (0,1,0)\} \\
E(2) = sp\{(1,1,1)\}$$

Not sure I understand this topic. Question is, if any eigen value has its own subspace and $\ V $ is always the direct sum of all the subspaces spanned by the eigen vectors, then the eigen vector/s of each value is a $\ T $ invariant subspace (Assume $\ T $ is diagnosable)?

Then in this case the $\ T $ invariant subspaces of $\ V $ are, $\ \mathbb R^3, \{0\} , \ \{(1,1,1)\} $ (dim 1) & $\ \{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\}$ (dim2)

Comment: There are many other 1 and 2-dimensional invariant subspaces, for example the span of $(1, 1, 0)$ is $T$-invariant, as is the span of $\{(1, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0)\}$.

Comment: Ok, read a little bit more and found that any subspace of the Eigenspaces is also $\ T -$ invariant, can't see why $\ {(1,1,1),(1,0,0)} $ is also $\ T- $ invariant though?

Comment: Any space spanned by a set of eigenvectors is invariant

Comment: Thanks! are there also T-invariant subspaces that are not spanned by a. set of eigenvectors ?

Comment: @bm No. The fact that $T$ is diagonalizable means that every $T$-invariant subspace is spanned by a set of eigenvectors.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't bother with "characteristic polynomials" or "characteristic numbers".  (x, y, z) is in an "invariant subspace" of T if and only if
$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} x+ z \\ y+ z \\ 2z \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix}$

So we have x+ z= x, y+ z= y, 2z= z.  All of those are satisfied if z=0, no matter what x and y are.  The invariant subspace is the two-dimensional subspace spanned by $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$